# Pass variable between events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an edit button that, when clicked, triggers the first event below. It(edit form) also have a cancel link that, when clicked, triggers the second event below. How do I ensure that the `PrevContent` value is accessible within the cancel event?  The user may click on any number of corresponding edit links at one time.

```
$('.js-profile-edit').live('click',function(){

    var TrBlock     = $(this).closest('tr');
    var PrevContent = TrBlock.html();
    var colspan     = TrBlock.parent().prev().find('a:first').first().data('span');

    $.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('href'),
        type    : 'GET',
        success : function(response){
            TrBlock.html('<td colspan="'+colspan+'">'+response+'</td>');
        },
        error    : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            uiAlert({message : 'Something Broke. Try again later'})
        }
    });
    return false;
});


$('.js-profile-edit-cancel').live('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').html(PrevContent);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Just an off-subject note, `.live()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7. I've been using `.delegate()` since then: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: @spryno724 so is delegate a drop in replacement for live. i tried on but that didn't work

Comment: For your case you would use something like, `$('body').delegate('.js-profile-edit', 'click', function() {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to store the `prevContent` as `.data()` on the closest `<tr>`:

```
$('.js-profile-edit').live('click',function(){

    var TrBlock     = $(this).closest('tr');
    var PrevContent = TrBlock.html();
    TrBlock.data({contents: PrevContent});  // save it
    ...
})

$('.js-profile-edit-cancel').live('click',function() {
    var TrBlock = $(this).closest('tr');
    TrBlock.html(TrBlock.data('contents'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: wouldn't that screw up the html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could stuff the `PrevContent` to the [data object](http://api.jquery.com/data/) of your cancel button.

Write in `js-profile-edit` click handler:

```
$('.js-profile-edit-cancel').data('PrevContent', PrevContent);
```

and read in `js-profile-edit-cancel` click handler:

```
var PrevContent = $(this).data('PrevContent');
```